# Jenkins: identify trigger type

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

Is there a way I can identify the trigger for the current build during execution. What I want is to identify if the trigger was an SCM change, cron trigger or user trigger. I have multiple triggers defined for a job and want to use trigger type as a parameter in the shell execution script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Rest API to get this info; here's an example:

http://jenkins.yourdomain.com/job/job_name/build_number/api/json?tree=actions[causes[shortDescription]]&pretty=true

returns

```
{
  "actions" : [
    {
      "causes" : [
        {
          "shortDescription" : "Started by an SCM change"
        }
      ]
    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) which can run a different shell script depending on the trigger type. It is not the perfect solution, but it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with groovy script. Check out my answer to [Jenkins Groovy: What triggered the build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545155/jenkins-groovy-what-triggered-the-build/31285364#31285364)
you can get the Cause object and then check for which subtype of cause it is
http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.html

Answer (score 0):

At http(s)://(your-jenkins-server)/jenkins/job/(job-name)/(job-number) , under the "Build Artifacts" and "Changes" sections (if you have them), you should see this icon: [image: An orange diamond with gears] .  The text next to it should state what caused the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the so-called build causes from anywhere (i.e. also within a sandbox) reaching for `currentBuild.getBuildCauses`, which gets you a JSON(typed, but still normally iterable) list of the current causes and some of their properties, e.g.:

```
[
  [
    _class: 'hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause',
    shortDescription: 'Started by user TLWHiTeC',
    userId: 'tlwhitec',
    userName: 'TLWHiTeC'
  ],
  [
    _class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause',
    shortDescription: 'Replayed #3'
  ]
]
```

This is documented in your Jenkins instance's pipeline syntax section covering global variables: `https://<jenkins-hostname>/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild`

You should iterate this list and look for the causes you're interested in. There's an *experimental* alternative `currentBuild.getBuildCauses(String fqcn)` that already filters the causes by the one you're interested in (via provided class name), so you can save yourself the iteration. Without guarantees for the future, though. Also it still returns a list...

The trigger types are [`hudson.model.Cause`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Cause.html) subclasses, e.g. [`hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Cause.UserIdCause.html) is the manually triggered one (the naming schema is `<package>.<class>[$<inner-class>]`).

Note that with the `currentBuild.getBuildCauses` you'll only get a JSON-dumped "fingreprint" of those objects, mostly with string to compare or print. It can be enough most of the time, but if you want the real deal you need to call [`currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getCauses()) **out of the sandbox**. This gets you the list of the actual objects to work with (e.g. access properties not present in the JSON dump).