# hudson: way to get the user value who initiated the build?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, build-automation, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

Is there a way to get the hudson job initiated user name.
Is it possible to get using script shell, py etc.

Lets assume I have the build # which was initiated. I know how to get the latest build info using api but would like to get a user details for a specific job.

Do you think, this will work for hudson? :)
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin

Thanks in advance

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545155/jenkins-groovy-what-triggered-the-build/31285364#31285364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin will not work with Hudson, unless you download a very old version of the plugin.  I'm not sure how many people are still using Hudson and haven't [upgraded to Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974032/234938).

---

Anyway, when a user manually triggers a build, this is called a "user cause"; there are other types of cause, e.g. SCM trigger.

You can use the JSON or XML API to get the causes for a build, for example:
https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/job/remoting/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/xml?xpath=//action/cause/userId

In this case, this returns the username that caused the build to run.
Though note that there may be multiple causes for a build, and *potentially* other cause types that use the `userId` field.

This works in Jenkins, but it *should* also work in Hudson, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thx Chris, is it possible to get the userid for a specific build #?

Comment: @enthuguy Yes, replace `lastSuccessfulBuild` in the URL with the build number. You can get API information for most URLs in Jenkins by adding `/api` to the end.