# How to run groovy script to read build cause?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am writing a first groovy script in the Jenkins, have an upstream `job A` which calls `job B`.

Being in job B I need to read GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER which triggered the job A.

In below e.g, how to get `28331` in the downstream job B?, its printed in the job B's console as below:

```
Started by upstream project some_up_project build number 100
originally caused by:

Triggered by Gerrit: https://gerrit-server.com/28331
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545155/jenkins-groovy-what-triggered-the-build) SO answer, but not sure how to do this in jenkins.

In job B, I did `Add build step` to add `Execute system Groovy script` section, then chose `Groovy command` in its dropdown, and in the Groovy Script area, added below for testing purpose, it gives error as `unable to resolve class Run.cause ...`, tried many other ways too and nothing worked.

```
import hudson.model.Run
for (cause in Run.getCauses()) {
    if (cause instanceof Run.Cause.UserIdCause) {
        println cause.getUserName()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no such class `Run.Cause`

start from something that works: `hudson.model.Run`

search for the documentation: [hudson.model.Run.getCauses()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getCauses--)

the method returns: List<[Cause](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.html)>

so, import this class into your code and use it:

```
import hudson.model.Cause
import hudson.model.Run
for (cause in Run.getCauses()) {
    if (cause instanceof Cause.UserIdCause) {
        println cause.getUserName()
    }
}
```

Note: I have not tested the code. I just gave you an idea how to resolve an error.